# What PHP/MySQL book would be good as a textbook?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm possibly teaching an **undergraduate PHP/MySQL course** in the Fall and was wondering if anyone has any recommendations for good textbooks.

The books have to be geared towards a **beginner/medium level** (I'm assuming/hoping my students will have C++ and MsSQL classes prior to mine).

Topics I want to cover in **PHP:**

- Variables/Constants
- Conditionals
- Loops/Loop Control
- Functions

  - Strings
  - Arrays
  - Dates
  - Custom
- Form Data
- Session/Cookie/Server variables
- MySQL integration

  - Query/Error
  - Prepared Statements
  - MySQLi Class

In **MySQL:**

- Schema/Users/Tables/Columns/Rows
- Primary/Foreign/Constraints
- Data Types
- Queries

  - Select/Update/Insert/Delete/Truncate
  - Limit/Order By/Group By

Possibly deal with:

- Stored Procedures/Triggers
- Image Manipulation/Custom Classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welling & Thomson's *PHP and MySQL Web Development* is the gold standard:

[http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Development-Developers-Library/dp/0672329166/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1236994701&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)

Comment: Out of all the books listed, this is the best one geared towards learning PHP and MySQL instead of building your first website.  Thank you!  I read the table of contents and think I will purchase this one!

Comment: I agree with @St.JohnJohnson, from the TOC it sounds like a great book.  I'm planning on buying it, but I would like to know what @St.JohnJohnson thought about it after he bought it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anyone who learned PHP from a book, just online tutorials or the PHP manual. I would say look on Amazon to find a book that covers the topics you want in your course.

Maybe like this. [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-PHP-MySQL-Novice-Professional/dp/1590598628/ref=pd_bbs_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1236970221&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598628)

Comment: The PHP CHM Manual is on my quick launch bar! :D

Comment: Well I learned from Larry Ullman's books, websites tend to be better at specific jobs but worse at explaining the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

[Programming PHP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006815/) covers all the PHP topics and then some except for the MySQL integration. It has a chapter on databases, but it is fairly basic. I would supplement this with another, MySQL specific book.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something from Wrox (i.e. Beginning PHP5). Their writers use pretty much comprensible language and examples are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I used PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Websites, from Larry Ullman and Peachpit. Not the most advanced book, but a good introduction to both. There have been a number of revisions to this book, I was using the second edition some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning using Head First's PHP and MySQL and have found it sound and useful.